# Nextjs 13 "not-found" isn't compatible with generateStaticParams?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using Nextjs 13's "generateStaticParams" function to throw 404s on routes that don't match with a set of ids in data I'm getting from another function like so:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await PostsData();
  return posts.map((post) => ({
    postId: post.id,
  }));
}
```

I'm looking for a way to have a custom 404 page. It is to my understanding that, in order to have a custom 404 page, you need to create a "not-found.tsx" page, and import "notFound" from "next/navigation." You then need to call "`notFound()`" if you're unable to find an item that matches the id found in your page params.

However, this notFound() function only routes users to the custom 404 if I remove `generateStaticParams()`. If that function is still present, users are still routed to Nextjs 13's default 404 page.

Are these two functions incompatible? Am I unable to have a custom 404 page if I want to use `generateStaticParams()`? Any help is greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: See Maciej Wira's comment. This solution may not be entirely complete.**

Figured out the answer shortly after. In order to prevent Nextjs from automatically generating pages even on routes that weren't statically generated, I was using:

```
export const dynamicParams = false;
```

Removing this line allows me to retain the SSG functionality on routes that exist, and calling `notFound()` allows me to route users to a custom 404 page defined by my content in `not-found.tsx`

Comment: Is that enough? Cause I have a similar case and I can render custom 404 page with notFound(), but the page itself has a 200 status.

Comment: @MaciejWira Honestly I'm not sure. I stopped using NextJS 13 and switched to SvelteKit. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: It has been fixed in the v13.4.17 https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.4.17 "Fix root not-found page tree loader structure"